# Compiler flags settings in CMAKE scripts

Tags: cmake

I am facing below issue while running my build:

```
C:/Test.cpp: In member function '........':
C:/Test.cpp:291:50: error: 'round_one' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
```

I tried to grep for string **maybe-uninitialized** in my whole source code but I could not find one. I was expecting some declaration like below:

```
set_source_files_properties(ROOT_DIR/Test.cpp PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Wno-misleading-indentation" )
```

or

```
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wno-maybe-uninitialized")
add_definitions(${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS})
```

But I could  not find any - please let me know how Compiler flags are set in CMAKE utility?

Comment: The simplest way is to look into compiler's command line (`make VERBOSE=1`), find a flag genereting this error, and grep your CMake scripts for this flag. By itself, CMake definitely do not pass `-Werror`.

Comment: As well as `make VERSBOSE=1` mentioned by @Tsyvarev , you can use `ccmake` or CMake GUI, and show the advanced view to check the flags defined in `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`...

Comment: I use CMAKE to build my system 2 time - first time I give the command "cmake -G "Ninja" ../.." where my CMakeLists.txt exists in ../... directory and then "cmake --build ." from same directory - please let me know where to use the VERBOSE flag? Using it in build command does not start the build process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning `-Wmaybe-uninitialized` is one of those that are enabled
by [`-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).
`-Wall` is always specified by proficient programmers. Warnings will be converted
to errors by [`-Werror`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options), so the flags `-Wall -Werror` will produce `-Werror=maybe-uninitialized`,
as per your diagnostic, if a potentially uninitialized variable is detected.

You will very likely find `-Wall ... -Werror` in the specified compiler flags in the relevant `CMakeLists.txt`

Answer (score 1):

One way is setting the add compiler flag for the project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# Project
project(008-compile-flags-01)

# Add compile flag
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DHELLO_WORLD" CACHE STRING "Hello World Define." FORCE)

# Executable source files
set(executable_SOURCES src/main.cpp)

# Executable
add_executable(executable ${executable_SOURCES})
```

Other way is setting compiler flag for the target:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

# Project
project(008-compile-flags-03)

# Executable source files
set(executable_SOURCES src/main.cpp)

# Executable
add_executable(executable ${executable_SOURCES})

# Add compile flag
target_compile_options(executable PRIVATE -DHELLO_WORLD)
```

Other way is using **target_compile_features**. I haven't used this before. Please see:

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html